# TextView attributes missing

Tags: android, android-studio

When I am in the design view, in the attributes pane for the TextView, attributes like Text and textSize are missing, same goes for the Button.

[image: Image 1]

Other examples:

- [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z696b.png)
- [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc0A4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to add them from the xml file, you can add these attributes in your views (needed ones):

```
android:textSize="15dp"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:textStyle="bold"
```

- Try to invalidate the cached and restart Android Studio, also make sure sure that you click on the views for the attributes to show in the design section.

Comment: After declaring the textSize attribute, its appearing, but the text Attribute is still not appearing, I can make do with this, hope they fix it in the next update, Anyways Thank You So Much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the modules in the project structure, I was facing the same issue, then edited my modules, changed compile SDK version, and build the tools version in the properties tab as well as the default Config tab.